# SQL find all rows in one table that also exist in another table

Tags: sql, select

I have the following tables:

1. `UserConversation`: userId and ConversationId
2. `ConversationMessageReceipt`: userId, conversationId, conversationMessageId and other columns
3. `ConversationMessageReceipt`: conversationId, conversationMessageId, userid

I could add more details but I basically want to find rows in one table that also exists in another table, that is all the rows found from first table have to exists in another table.

Is there a way to find all the rows in the second table or get empty results?

Thanks

Comment: It's kind of hard to explain but basically if you have two tables and I  want to find all rows from one table existing in another table.  If all the rows are not found in second table then I do not want any results from the second table.

Comment: I think left join is probably what I need to find rows from first table in second table or none.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to check the table1 data in table 2,  you can also use EXISTS keyword..

```
 SELECT *
 FROM UserConversation uc
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM ConversationMessageReceipt cm
    WHERE uc.userId=cm.userid
       AND uc.conversationid=cm.conversationid)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try joining them like below:

```
SELECT *
FROM UserConversation uc INNER JOIN ConvesationMessageReceipt cmr
ON  uc.userId = cmr.userId
AND uc.conversationId = cmr.conversationId
```

Comment: @Sonam: Note, that this might (and probably will) return rows from `UserConversation` multiple times. If you only want to see each row from `UserConversation`  only once, the `exists` version from Unnikrishnan is better

Answer (score 1):

Use INNER JOIN your scenario,

```
SELECT * FROM UserConversation INNER JOIN ConvesationMessageReceipt
ON  UserConversation.userId = ConvesationMessageReceipt.userId
AND UserConversation.conversationId = ConvesationMessageReceipt.conversationId
```

OR You want to get all records from first table Use LEFT JOIN Or LEFT OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT * FROM UserConversation LEFT JOIN ConvesationMessageReceipt
ON  UserConversation.userId = ConvesationMessageReceipt.userId
AND UserConversation.conversationId = ConvesationMessageReceipt.conversationId
```